# Jquery , Html Append value to textfield when Checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of four check boxes which are as shown below :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxstyle"  id="id_peer_educator" value="Peer Educator"/>Peer Educator<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxstyle"  id="id_chw" value="CHW"/>CHW<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxstyle"  id="id_health_provider" value="Health Prvider"/>Health Provider<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxstyle"  id="id_purchase" value="Purchase"/>Purchase<br>
<input type="text" id="CD_Supplr" class="CD_Supplr" name="CD_Supplr" placeholder=" Suppliers : "/>
```

The first four are check boxes while the last one is a textbox. How can I append data to the text-field Suppliers ? (When it is checked , it should be appended to the  text field Supplier, if it is unchecked, then the  value should be removed from the  text field supplier) .

I tried implementing it the following way :

```
var CD_Supplr = $('#CD_Supplr').val();
var id_peer_educator = $('#id_peer_educator').val();
var id_chw = $('#id_chw').val();
var id_health_provider = $('#id_health_provider').val();
var id_purchase = $('#id_purchase').val();

$('#id_peer_educator').click(function () {
    $('#CD_Supplr').val(CD_Supplr + "," + id_peer_educator;
});

$('#id_chw').click(function () {
    $('#CD_Supplr').val(CD_Supplr + "," + id_chw;
});
```

But it's not working,what's the best way to implement it?

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket for the `.val(CD_Supplr + ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/phwrohL2/1/)

```
$('.checkboxstyle').on("change",function () 
{
    var str ="";
    $('.checkboxstyle:checked').each(function()
    {
        str+= $(this).val()+" ";
    });
    $('#CD_Supplr').val(str);

});
```

Comment: did you try the Demo ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `array` to add value when `checkbox` is checked and remove it when unchecked and use `join()` function to join the array values by dispay in `input`.

Hope this helps.

```js
var selected_checkbox=[];

$('.checkboxstyle').change(function()
{
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
        //If checked add it to the array
        selected_checkbox.push($(this).val());
   } 
   else 
   {
      //If unchecked remove it from array
      for (var i=selected_checkbox.length-1; i>=0; i--) 
      {
          if (selected_checkbox[i] === $(this).val()) 
              selected_checkbox.splice(i, 1);
      }
   }
    $('#CD_Supplr').val(selected_checkbox.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxstyle"  id="id_peer_educator" value="Peer Educator"/>Peer Educator<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxstyle"  id="id_chw" value="CHW"/>CHW<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxstyle"  id="id_health_provider" value="Health Prvider"/>Health Provider<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxstyle"  id="id_purchase" value="Purchase"/>Purchase<br>
<input type="text" id="CD_Supplr" class="CD_Supplr" name="CD_Supplr" size='50' placeholder=" Suppliers : "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add listeners to the `change` event on the checkboxex, then using `match()` find out if the value of a checkbox is NOT already there in the `CD_Suplr` textbox. Then, use the result of this condition to add/remove the checkbox values:

```
var $target = $('#CD_Supplr');
$('[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($target.val() == ''){
        $target.val('Supplier: '); //default text
    }
    if(!$target.val().match($(this).val())){
        var text = $target.val();
        $target.val(text + ' ' + $(this).val() + ', ');
    } else {
        var text = $target.val();
        $target.val(text.replace($(this).val()+', ', ''));
    }
    //make sure the last comma is removed
    $target.val($target.val().replace(/\,$/, ''));
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/bL372gt1/).